# What is the tightest asymptotic bound for this recurrence?

Tags: time-complexity, recurrence-relation

$$T(n) = T\left(\frac{n}{2}\right) + T\left(\frac{n}{4}\right) + T\left(\frac{n}{8}\right) + n$$

How do you solve this recurrence?

Comment: Use the Akra-Bazzi theorem.

Answer (score 1):

It will be $\Theta(n)$, to save myself from rewriting an entire answer, I will refer you to [this question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/79790/68251) and you can apply the answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Because in each recurrence you are cutting $n$ by half you will have at most $log(n)$ calls, if you use memorization, memorization will make your code faster because you will avoid overlapping calls, because $T(n/4) = T(n/2/2)$.

If $n$ is small number and you can use normall array for storing the values the complexity will be $O(\log n)$, but if n is big (up to $10^{18}$) then you can optimaze by using some data structures (map in c++) to make the complexity $O((\log n)^2)$

Comment: It can't be less than $\Omega(n)$ because there is already $n$ work being done at the highest level.

Comment: I don't understand you why do we need linear complexity to solve this recurrence, for example if $n = 32$ we don't need to calculate T(31) or T(30), we can just calculate T(32), T(16), T(8), T(4), T(2), T(1), we calculate $\log N$ values so the complexity is $O(\log N)$, can you explain more clearly.

Comment: The implicit assumption is that the recurrence represents the running time of *some* recursive algorithm. This is typically what *recurrence* relations are for. If this were simply a function, not a recurrence relation, then sure you could solve the function in less than $\Omega(n)$.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, I didn't get the different between recurrence relation and function, should I remove my answer from this post?